# Слово "лодырь"

Tags: этимология

От какого слова происходит слово "лодырь"?

Answer (score 3):

«…В ряду модных явлений обыденной общественной жизни в двадцатых годах нынешнего (прим.: XIX) столетия особенно резко сказалась страсть аристократического общества к лечению минеральными водами. Новизна и мода влекла праздное общество к питью кислых вод. В эти годы весною вся аристократическая Москва просыпалась уже в пятом часу утра и катила на всевозможных экипажах в заведение старого московского врача **Лодера**, устроенное над Москвой-рекой близ Крымского брода. Лодер вместе с молодым доктором Енихеном первый завел в России искусственные минеральные воды. Помещались они в очень обширном саду с галереями. Здесь уже в пятом часу утра гремела музыка, и бродили толпы гуляющих больных. В первые годы больше всего лечились дамы и затем старики-сановники от неизлечимой болезни старости…
По предписанию Лодера при питье вод больные должны были ходить три часа; эта-то ходьба, на взгляд простолюдина бесцельная, и вызвала поговорку, характеризующую праздную гуляку: «**Лодерем** ходит»…»

Источник: М. Пыляев, «Старое житье» (СПб., изд-во А. С. Суворина, 1892; 2-е изд., Санкт-Петербург, 1897).

Comment: Интересная история, но к слову "лодырь" вряд ли имеет отношение. Да и автор не был, прямо скажем, лингвистом.

Answer (score 1):

От немецкого Lodder, Lotterbube. Говорят, что немцы завезли при Петре, когда ругались на наших бездельников :)

Answer (score 0):

Приведу выдержку из большой статьи в "Историко-этимологическом словаре" П.Я. Черных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По многочисленным просьбам одного из более опытных участников привожу отдельно ключевую мысль из процитированной статьи:

> Происхождение слова *лодырь* не вполне ясно.

Comment: Ответ — в студию... Он будет?

Comment: @shampar Не смог однозначно понять смысл Вашего комментария. Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вы не видите изображение части страницы из словаря в моём ответе?

Comment: Уверен, что никто не видит ответа. Если grizzly не псевдоним П.Я. Черных.

Comment: @shampar Я снова затрудняюсь Вас понять, потому что Вы забыли ответить на мой вопрос. Вы уверены, что никто не видит изображение? При чём здесь псевдоним? У меня появилась совершенно новая гипотеза, но я боюсь, что она может Вас задеть: неужели Вы думаете, что про любое слово можно однозначно выяснить, от какого другого слова оно происходит? Если Вас не интересуют другие мои гипотезы, постарайтесь выражать свои мысли более понятным образом, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ни других, ни ту, которая якобы задевает, тоже не вижу. Вижу скан словарной статьи. Где ваш ответ? Выделите эти слова в единственной строке, которую предлагаете считать ответом.

Comment: @shampar Моим ответом является вся цитата, кроме последней полустрочки. Я уверен, что многим будут интересны эти детали. Если Вы находите в этом тексте что-то лишнее, Вы имеете право предложить свой ответ. Надеюсь, мы теперь полностью понимаем друг друга в этом диалоге.

Comment: После правки всё встало на свои места, спасибо за понимание.